# Running Django without web server

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, nginx

I am not too much familiar with Django,(till now developed only 2-3 apps and used apache).

The question is can we run django without apache or nginx or any HTTPserver, just like the development server.

I don't want to install apache+mod_wsgi or nginx+uwsgi, just want to run a command

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8080
```

And i should be able to access the site using my server's IP address on port 8080

Answer (score 0):

if you do

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080`

then it will respond on all IP addresses not just local. I wouldn't strongly recommend against this for production, but for local development and testing it's fine.